# Existe um nome para palavras cuja pronúncia muda ao passarem do singular para o plural

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, pronúncia

Recentemente eu ouvi diversas palavras que, pelo menos em PT-BR, mudam a pronúncia da letra o de fechada (como o *o* em “todo”) para aberta (como o *o* em “cola”).

Alguns exemplos:

- Um olho → dois olhos (pronunciado-se [ôlhu] e [ólhus])
- Um ovo → dois ovos (pronunciado-se [ôvu] e [óvus])
- Um jogo → dois jogos (pronunciado-se [jôgu] e [jógus])
- Um posto → dois postos (pronunciado-se [pôstu] e [póstus])

Existe um nome para tal característica do idioma português?

Como bônus, o mesmo ocorre em PT-PT?

<sub>PS: não sei usar a notação do [alfabeto fonético internacional](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfabeto_fon%C3%A9tico_internacional), se alguém quiser editar
a questão com este intuito, sinta-se convidado para tal.</sub>

Comment: Tudo isso está no Priberam: pos·to |ô|, depois de cada uma das palavras. Claro que muda. Igualzinho.  É só olhar aqui: https://dicionario.priberam.org/postos//o·lho |ô|

"olhos", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/olhos [consultado em 01-06-2021].

Comment: Acho que não entenderam a pergunta.  Gmauch está **a procura de um termo** para essas palavras que mudam a pronuncia ao serem passadas para o plural.

Comment: Só uma correção, o plural de "ôlho" é "óilhos"!  (É sotaque do Minho...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correção: **existe** uma regra para isso.
Veja-se [a resposta alternativa posta por Wander de Castro Silva](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/8752/157).

---

De acordo com o FLiP, <del>**não** existe tal regra ou nome para ela</del>:

> Não existe oficialmente nenhuma regra fonética em português que dê conta da alternância vocálica entre o singular e o plural de palavras como *fogo*, *poço*, *jogo*, *contorno*, *despojo*, *esforço*, *imposto*, *ovo*, *tijolo*, *troço*.

https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/452

O artigo alonga-se um pouco mais sobre o tema; recomendo a leitura. :)

Comment: Tangencialmente, eu gosto desta ratoeira bem portuguesa: há molho [ô] -> molhos [ô] para "sauce(s)", e molho [ó] -> molhos [ó] para p.e. braçada(s) de legumes... mas comummente usa-se [erradamente](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/638) uma mistura dos dois: "temos um m[ô]lho doce e dois m[ó]lhos picantes".

Comment: Ótima referência! Só achei estranho que em PT-BR (eu ao menos) pronuncio "contorno" sempre fechado e troço sempre aberto, ambos tanto no singular quanto no plural!

Comment: Também conheço essas pronúncias dessa forma, @gmauch, com uma exceção: "troço" é só com |ó| no sentido de "coisa", no sentido de "pedaço de matéria fecal", é com |ô| - como colocado no [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/tro%C3%A7o), embora, ao contrário do descrito no verbete, tendo a usar o |ô| tanto no singular, quanto no plural desse segundo significado.

Answer (score 5):

Salvo melhor entendimento, tal regra denomina-se "Plurais Metafônicos".

Links:

- https://www.estrategiaconcursos.com.br/blog/plural-metafonico
- https://www.plurais.com.br/atividades-educativas-com-plurais/lista-de-plural-metafonico.php;
- https://www.resumoescolar.com.br/portugues/plural-metafonico-dos-substantivos
- https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/plural-metafonicometafonico/5959

Atenciosamente,

Comment: Bem vindo Wander! Que bom que tens o nome do fenômeno linguístico que eu buscava. Vou buscar mais informações a respeito. Peço encarecidamente, que se tiveres algum link sobre este fenômeno, que o adicione a sua resposta, de forma a deixá-la mais completa.

Comment: Wander, adicionei o link de uma fonte confiável para português europeu. Acho que complementa bem as outras ligações que já tinhas. (Se não gostares, por favor simplesmente edita a pergunta e retira-a de lá! :)

Comment: Ficou muito bom! Obrigado, Aneves. Pena q a resposta toda como correta no posto não é a nossa